# Postgres: modify existing search_path (preserve current values)

Tags: postgresql, schema

Sometimes I would like to extend the existing search path, rather than replace it, say:

To start with say it is already set like so:

```
SET search_path TO schema_b, schema_c, public;
```

I want to add my schema to the front of the line:

```
SET search_path TO schema_a + search_path;   --doesn't work
```

I'm thinking in analogy to what I'd do in BASH:

```
PATH=path_a:$PATH
```

Bonus question, perhaps related: is there a way I can store the current path temporarily, so I can change it to something totally different, and then restore it without having to know what it was?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
SELECT set_config('search_path', 'fred,'||current_setting('search_path'), false);
```

The `false` says it's not a transaction-`LOCAL` setting.

For the bonus question, you can store the value in a [custom setting](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/runtime-config-custom.html):

```
SELECT set_config('tmp.search_path', current_setting('search_path'), false);
```

From version 9.2 on, you don't even have to define this setting in `postgresql.conf`.

Comment: this seems to be only temporary, is there a way to do this constantly?

Comment: Maybe some way to use `SELECT set_cont('search_path'}` as a subselect in `ALTER USER name SET search_path ...`

Comment: @vrms `ALTER USER ... SET` , `ALTER DATABASE .. SET` or `ALTER SYSTEM .. SET`

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do this is to originally set the `search_path` in a two-step procedure:

```
\set my_path schema_b, schema_c, public
set search_path to :my_path;
```

Then, whenever you want to extend `search_path`, do it like so:

```
\set my_path schema_a, :my_path
set search_path to :my_path;
```

This does not allow for storing the existing value of `search_path` however.

Answer (score 2):

A nice way to do this is using the 9.3-specific `\gset` psql command:

```
SELECT current_setting('search_path') AS my_path \gset
set search_path to schema_a, :my_path;
```

`\gset` is documented [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/app-psql.html) and is demonstrated nicely on [depesz.com](http://www.depesz.com/2013/02/03/waiting-for-9-3-create-a-psql-command-gset-to-store-query-results-into-psql-variables/).

I was not able to test this as I don't have access to an instance of 9.3. I'd be grateful to anyone who could confirm to me that this works as I have outlined. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Adapted from  the answer from Craig Ringer: if you want to make a check for distinct values, use the following query:

```sql
SELECT set_config('search_path', '"$user", mview,'||ARRAY_TO_STRING(
    ARRAY(
        SELECT DISTINCT elem FROM
        UNNEST(
            STRING_TO_ARRAY(
            REPLACE(
                current_setting('search_path'), ' ', '')
            , ',')) elem
        WHERE elem <> '"$user"')
    ,','), false);
```

It will make sure:

- `"$user"` is always at the beginning of the search_path
- no duplicate entries in search path
- whitespace is removed on count-distinct check
- replace `mview` with your new search path entry of choice